# Android Studio: keyboard shortcut to show the error on the current line?

Tags: android, android-studio

The only way I have found to show the error of an underlined piece of code is to hover it with the mouse.

[image]

**What is the keyboard shortcut to achieve this?** (when the cursor is on the line in error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Mac that's Command-F1 (in the menu bar it's View -> Error Description). I think that's Control-F1 on Windows.

Comment: Yep, it's Control-F1. The behavior of the menu button `View` > `Error Description` is weird by the way: it does not display the pop-up (as the shortcut does), but only the error message in Android Studio "status bar" at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You should try using Alt+Enter key. This will recommend you the available solution for your error.

Also try using Ctrl+F1 it will give you a detailed information for your error.

P.S. these shortcuts are for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

F2 is shortcut key to jump on next error line 
please note that cursor must be in java file for this to work.