# Button type does not exist in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on my first app in Android Studio and have created a button "buttonFish" in the xml creator that I now want to put an action onto in the mainactivity.java.
This is my code:

```
package com.example.acfaunapedia;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Private Button butf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        butF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFish);
    }
}
```

It can find my Button but it doesnt recognize the Type "Button".
Any ideas on how to fix this?

[Error Message Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rze7M.png)

EDIT:
I created an empty activity to start with, but I don't think thats relevant.

Comment: `private` must be lowercase, as it is a Java keyword.

Comment: You are missing the import for the Button type. Set the current on the missing type and use `Ctr` + `Enter` conbination to execute Android Studio quick fix and import missing type. Or make the import manual `import android.widget.Button;`

Comment: @Salatgurke (Mr. Cucumber, in English): have you resolved the problem?  By a) changing `Private` to `private` (resolving the compile error), and b) importing `android.widget.Button`?

Comment: Yes I solved it. Thanks you all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alt-Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136668/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-show-the-error-on-the-current-line) is your friend.  This Android Studio shortcut key will prompt you for solution(s) to error messages.

In this case, it will probably prompt you to add `import android.widget.Button` in your source, which should resolve the problem.

ALSO:

In the future, please copy/paste the error message text into your post.  "Text" is generally more helpful than "screenshots" ;)

Here's the error (from your screenshot):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Private Button butf;  // <-- Cannot resolve symbol 'butf'
```

As nanofarad pointed out, the problem isn't "Buttom" per se (although that *IS* a problem), it's that you said "Private" instead of keyword `private`.

Alt-Enter should help with *ANY* error.

And once again: "Generally, text is better than screenshots"

Comment: Alt+enter for import probably won't resolve this since the code isn't parsing to begin with. It appears to parse as *class-identifier identifier [missing-semicolon]...*, suggesting that `Private` ought to be `private` instead, for a valid parse. Only then will importing be helpful.